# "get" rest api with golang and mondoDB atlas won't work

Tags: mongodb, api, go

I am trying to build a website using golang for the backend and mongoDB atlas as the db. I have a collection in my db called "users" with one entry.

When I use postman, retrieving the collection is successful, but the data says null.

Any and all help is appreciated! TIA

Here is my "GET" function:
`

```
func GetAllUsers(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    var users []models.User
    defer cancel()
  
    results, err := userCollection.Find(ctx, bson.M{})
  
    if err != nil {
        return c.Status(http.StatusInternalServerError).JSON(responses.UserResponse{Status: http.StatusInternalServerError, Message: "error", Data: &fiber.Map{"data": err.Error()}})
    }
  
    //reading from the db in an optimal way
    defer results.Close(ctx)
    for results.Next(ctx) {
        var singleUser models.User
        if err = results.Decode(&singleUser); err != nil {
            return c.Status(http.StatusInternalServerError).JSON(responses.UserResponse{Status: http.StatusInternalServerError, Message: "error", Data: &fiber.Map{"data": err.Error()}})
        }
      
        users = append(users, singleUser)
    }
  
    return c.Status(http.StatusOK).JSON(
        responses.UserResponse{Status: http.StatusOK, Message: "success", Data: &fiber.Map{"data": users}},
    )
}
```

`

Here is Postman:
[image]

Here is db entry:
[image]

I expected to see the entry.

Comment: Likely you used a wrong database or collection name. That won't give you any error, but will not return any documents of course either. And simply use `results.All(users)` instead of the loop.